# Create a list of drop-down names based on dates/time

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm learning excel and trying to make a shift schedule for employees. Is there a way to make a drop-down menu of available employees depending on what day/time they are assigned? For example I have a schedule for November 9 and out of my 5 employees A B C D E, only A D E are on shift that day. Can I create a drop-down menu that only shows A D E, instead of all 5 employees? Thanks

I tried doing it manually but I've been looking for a way to automate it better, otherwise it'll just be better to not use macros.

Comment: You can use a macro that runs the "special filter" to copy those employees that meet the desired criteria into a separate range of cells, which you can then use as source for your drop-down liist.

Answer (score 1):

- Save the code into worksheet module.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Column = Range("I1").Column Then
            If IsDate(.Offset(0, -1)) Then
                .Validation.Delete
                Dim tabRange As Range, iRow, sList As String, c As Range
                Set tabRange = Me.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
                iRow = Application.Match(CLng(.Offset(0, -1)), tabRange.Columns(1), 0)
                If Not IsError(iRow) Then
                    For Each c In tabRange.Rows(iRow).Cells
                        If StrComp(c.Value, "x", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            sList = sList & "," & Me.Cells(1, c.Column)
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Len(sList) Then
                        .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
                            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Mid(sList, 2)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

*Testing data:*

| Date | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/11/2023 | X |  | X | X |  |
| 26/11/2023 | X | X |  |  | X |
| 27/11/2023 | X | X |  | X | X |
| 28/11/2023 |  | X |  |  | X |
| 29/11/2023 |  |  | X |  | X |

Comment: Use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table.

Comment: Select A1:F6 > Insert > Table  ...